# Recursively call http.post and return observable at last iteration

Tags: angular, recursion, observable

I have the list of documents to attach and each document can have max 20 MB data and the user can attach any number of files, therefore I am sending one file per rest call.

Once all the documents are saved, then redirect the user to showStudent page.

Here is my code, but the problem is, it works for only a single file. I want to wait until all the documents are saved.

```
uploadAttachments(student: Student, documents: Document[]): Observable<Response> {
    let status;

    let user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));
    let userId = user.id;
    let headers = new Headers({
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('token')
    });
    let url = environment.userResourceEndpoint + userId + "/documents/attach";
    let body;

    let document = documents[index];
    body = new FormData();
    console.log("###############Uploading document:" + document.title);
    let fileUpload: File = document.file;
    body.append('attachTo', 'student');
    body.append('attachToId', student.id);
    body.append('title', document.title);
    body.append('file', fileUpload, fileUpload.name);

    return this.http.post(url, body, headers)
        .map((res: Response) => {
            res.json() as Student;
            if (index < documents.length - 1) {
                index = index + 1;
                this.uploadAttachments(student, documents);
            }
        })
        .catch((error: any) => {
            if (error.status === 0) {
                console.log(" Server is down???");
            }
            return Observable.throw(error);
        });
}
```

Comment: TLDR; Use switchMap for that maybe

Comment: Have you read about using `Observable.forkJoin()`? You can read more about it from here: https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/forkjoin.html

Comment: If you remove the upload operation and just have a recursive operation which writes file information to console, is it working ?

Comment: @SourangshuSengupta, I am looking into it. NitinSingh I have not tried that yet. I'll have a look into that as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have gone through the link that @SourangshuSengupta sent me and implemented the solution and it works.

Here is the complete method code for reference:

```
uploadAttachments(user: User, documents: Document[]): Observable<any> {
    let status;
    let observableObj = new Observable<Response>();
    let user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));
    let userId = user.id;
    let headers = new Headers({
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('token')
    });
    let url = environment.userResourceEndpoint + userId + "/documents/attach";
    let body;
    let observables = [];
    documents.forEach(item => {
        body = new FormData();
        let fileUpload: File = item.file;
        body.append('attachTo', 'user');
        body.append('attachToId', user.id);
        body.append('title', item.title);
        body.append('file', fileUpload, fileUpload.name);

        observables.push(this.http.post(url, body, headers).map(res => res.json()));
    });

    return Observable.forkJoin(observables)
        .map(res => res.length)
        .catch((error: any) => {
            if (error.status === 0) {
                console.log(" Server is down???");
            }
            return Observable.throw(error);
        });
}
```